# Custom Cursor is not showing on Laptop with touch functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a custom cursor with Javascript and hide the default cursor. The custom cursor should of course be hidden on mobile devices. However, it was reported that users using a laptop that also has touch functionality don't see the cursor.

I toggle the cursor visbility on mouse events, such as `mousemove`, `mouseenter`, `mouseleave`. I know that there are equivalenet events such as `touchmove` etc., but this would also trigger it on mobile touch devices and the cursor should be hidden on mobile.

TLDR:

- I want to show the custom cursor on laptop + touch functionality and desktop devices
- I want to hide the custom cursor on mobile devices, including iPads

How do I do that?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var cursor = {
        delay: 4,
        _x: 0,
        _y: 0,
        endX: (window.innerWidth / 2),
        endY: (window.innerHeight / 2),
        cursorVisible: true,
        cursorEnlarged: false,
        $dot: document.querySelector('.cursor-dot'),
        $outline: document.querySelector('.cursor-dot-outline'),

        init: function () {
            // Set up element sizes
            this.dotSize = this.$dot.offsetWidth;
            this.outlineSize = this.$outline.offsetWidth;

            this.setupEventListeners();
            this.animateDotOutline();
        },

        setupEventListeners: function () {
            var self = this;
            const CLICKABLE_ELEMENTS = 'a, button, select, .filter-boolean';

            document.querySelectorAll(CLICKABLE_ELEMENTS).forEach(function (el) {
                el.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
                    self.cursorEnlarged = true;
                    self.toggleCursorSize();
                });
                el.addEventListener('mouseout', function () {
                    self.cursorEnlarged = false;
                    self.toggleCursorSize();
                });
            });

            // Click events
            document.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
                self.cursorEnlarged = true;
                self.toggleCursorSize();
            });
            document.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
                self.cursorEnlarged = false;
                self.toggleCursorSize();
            });


            document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
                // Show the cursor
                self.cursorVisible = true;
                self.toggleCursorVisibility();

                // Position the dot
                self.endX = e.clientX;
                self.endY = e.clientY;
                self.$dot.style.top = self.endY + 'px';
                self.$dot.style.left = self.endX + 'px';
            });

            // Hide/show cursor
            document.addEventListener('mouseenter', function (e) {
                self.cursorVisible = true;
                self.toggleCursorVisibility();
                self.$dot.style.opacity = 1;
                self.$outline.style.opacity = 1;
            });

            document.addEventListener('mouseleave', function (e) {
                self.cursorVisible = true;
                self.toggleCursorVisibility();
                self.$dot.style.opacity = 0;
                self.$outline.style.opacity = 0;
            });
        },

        animateDotOutline: function () {
            var self = this;

            self._x += (self.endX - self._x) / self.delay;
            self._y += (self.endY - self._y) / self.delay;
            self.$outline.style.top = self._y + 'px';
            self.$outline.style.left = self._x + 'px';

            requestAnimationFrame(this.animateDotOutline.bind(self));
        },

        toggleCursorSize: function () {
            var self = this;

            if (self.cursorEnlarged) {
                self.$dot.style.transform = 'translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.75)';
                self.$outline.style.transform = 'translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1.5)';
            } else {
                self.$dot.style.transform = 'translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1)';
                self.$outline.style.transform = 'translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1)';
            }
        },

        toggleCursorVisibility: function () {
            var self = this;

            if (self.cursorVisible) {
                self.$dot.style.opacity = 1;
                self.$outline.style.opacity = 1;
            } else {
                self.$dot.style.opacity = 0;
                self.$outline.style.opacity = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    cursor.init();
});
```

```css
html, body, html *, body * {
     cursor: none;
}

.cursor-dot-outline {
     pointer-events: none;
     position: fixed;
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     border-radius: 50%;
     opacity: 0;
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
     transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out, transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
 .cursor-dot {
     width: 8px;
     height: 8px;
     background-color: transparent;
z-index: 99999;
}
 .cursor-dot-outline {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #b560d5;
    z-index: 99999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cursor-dot-outline"></div>
<div class="cursor-dot"></div>
```

I'm thankful for any help!